# Accessing SSAS Cube Through SSRS URL

Tags: url, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssas

I'm using URLs in a word document to access an SSRS report which is sitting on top of an SSAS cube. We're pushing a URL like this through:

http://{server}/ReportServer?/Name/Name2/ProjectIR&rs:Command=Render&rc:Toolbar=False&rs:ClearSession=true&ParamItemType=Total%20Count

And it's just telling us that:

*Default value or value provided for the report parameter is not a valid value.*

Is there something special we need to pass through the URL because we're accessing an SSAS cube?

We've tried changing the space to %20 or + and we've added rp: before the parameter. Basically any little fix we could find on the internet we've tried. We're thinking it's the cube.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you access to the report through reporting server site?

Comment: So we actually got it working. By using a link like this:
http://{server}/Reportserver/?/Name/Name2/ProjectIR&rs:Command=Render&rc:Toolbar=False&CashFlowItemItemType=%5bParam%20Item%20Type%5d.%26%5bTotal%20Count%5d

Any idea why this works? Or what this solution is?

Comment: If you can access to the report via reporting server site the problem is the parameter value you are passing to the report through the url. there is nothing you need to pass if the report is on top a cube, you can pass values for parameters via url, it is not related to the cube itself but the queries.

Comment: @Skip that's just standard URL encoding of square brackets. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp You have to use the proper "key" value that matches how you setup the parameter drop downs. Typically with SSAS that's the MDX unique name like you used.

Answer (score 0):

what works for you, when unescaped is CashFlowItemI‌​temType=[Param I‌​tem Type].&[‌​Total Count]
It's common in SQL server to reference a table / field / index name containing a space by surrounding the name by square brackets so it knows the white space is in the name and not whitespace separating statements. The "&" in MDX differentiates Member key from member name:  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0ebde41d-bf60-44d2-a6ee-878e9973bd23/simple-mdx-question?forum=sqlanalysisservices